# Хочу найти в массиве псевдослучайных чисел отрицательные числа и запихнуть их в новый массив

Tags: c, массивы

Вот мой код на Си:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

const int N = 10;

main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int a, b, c, d, i, k, A[N], K[N], j;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        A[i] = rand() % 100 - 50;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("%4d", A[i]);
    }


    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if(A[i] < 0){
            for(j = 0; j < i; j++){
                K[j] = A[i];
                printf("%d", K[j]);
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Что с ним не так , почему он игнорирует первое отрицательное число и многократно выводит одно и тоже

Comment: Попробуйте `srand(time(NULL));`

Comment: Но у меня ведь это написано уже

Comment: хм дичь какая-то, а попробуй `srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) );`

Comment: тот же результат :(

Comment: А вы попробуйте просто вручную 0..5 поставить вместо time, посмотрите что будет

Comment: а что от изменения этого параметра поменяется ?

Comment: Вообще странно, в интернет C++ компиляторе вставил, всё чётко генерируется

Comment: Генерируемые комбинации, ну типа seed

Comment: я на dev-c++ и получаю стремный результат

Comment: @Elvin первый игнорируется, потомучто  0<0 - нет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы что-то странное делаете при копировании найденного отрицательного числа. Вам надо разделить копирование и вывод нового массива.

Вот такой вариант будет работать. Запустить код в [ideone](http://ideone.com/EjueN2).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

const int N = 10;

main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i, j, A[N], K[N];

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        A[i] = rand() % 100 - 50;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("%4d", A[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0, j = 0; i < 10; i++){
        /* если число меньше нуля */
        if(A[i] < 0){
            /* копируем его в новый массив */
            K[j] = A[i];
            /* увеличиваем индекс для нового массива */
            j++;
        }
    }    
    /* в этом месте j содержит длину нового массива */

    for(i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        printf("%4d", K[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: В смысле, а как так? В чём подвох? Мне просто очень интересно

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy проблема не в генерации чисел, а в копировании.

Comment: А в чём проблема копирования?

Comment: А вы когда внутри цикла увеличиваете значение j на 1 получаете следующее : K[0] , потом K[1] и так далее ,увеличиваете оба параметра (i и j ) я правильно понял ?

Comment: @Elvin `i` увеличивается в каждой итерации, а `j` только после копирования.